# Get the current page number using turn js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using turn js , a js that create flip book function.

From the online source the statement to get current page is :

```
alert($('selector').turn('page'));
```

However, it only get a null value that means the $('selector').turn('page') is not working. How to get the page no of the user reading page. Since a book have 2 page at the same time, I would like to get the page either left hand side or right hand side, How to do this ? Thanks

Comment: The answer depends entirely upon your HTML mark-up, and your current jQuery. Can you post both? And, ideally, a representative/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) live demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Comment: 'selector' is an HTML tag type. Perhaps it's the elements ID (a # in front) needed in the input? $('#selector').turn('page');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should change `'selector'` to the id of the div containing the 'pages'

eg:

```
<div id='flipbook'>
    <div class="hard"> Turn.js </div> 
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div> Page 1 </div>
    <div> Page 2 </div>
    <div> Page 3 </div>
    <div> Page 4 </div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
</div>
```

and in js

```
alert($('#flipbook').turn('page')); //do not forget the #
```

if you post a little more code, we can help you more :)

[if you click here](http://jsfiddle.net/A9a7E/2296/) you can see a working example with code

edit: added some event handling in the fiddle